# What's the efficient way to retrieve images from Firebase in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I need to store images in `Firebase - storage` and download them to every connected devices as soon as the image is added to the storage. However, what is the efficient way to achieve this?

- Should a [Firebase-job-dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) be used for this purpose?
- Or is there any listener/methods that fetches the images and sync the storage?

The [Download Files on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) docs from Firebase does explain various methods to retrieve the files such as : by bytes, via URL, FirebaseUI. However from the app perspective, how do I **listen** for any change in the storage(insertion/deletion of an image) and thereby performing operations in Firebase? If a new image is inserted, download it, or if its deleted, remove from app memory.

Any info regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Firebase database and having image url properties pointing to your images.  This info will get synced back to client and you can then use something like Picasso to render the image (using the url).

Comment: It is not to render the image, I need to download the image , it is for an offline image matching for an AR app

Comment: same general approach applies....you can download image though some other means or use Picasso to download the image as well.  The key point I think is use of Firebase db so client knows when image has been added.

Comment: Does picasso sync the image when the app is not open?

Comment: I think there's 2 parts to what you're looking for.  One is way for client to know that image has been added (and this is where Firebase db would come in).....the other is the actual downloading of the image.  Regardless of the approach you take for this you'll need app to be actually running.

Comment: So, last point is not strictly true....you could use Firebase Push Notifications for example if you wanted to send notification when app wasn't running.

Comment: There are Firebase listeners to listen if a child has been added ,removed and updated, however does it work when the app is not running? Or should I be running a jobScheduler and check everytime ?

Comment: This is where Firebase Push Notifications would potentially come in (https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/).

Comment: Sounds good, so when the app is invoked with a GCM, launch a service and fetch image ?

Comment: Yes, or wait until app starts and sync then